# How can I have Luma Files in My Magento 2.0?

Tags: magento-2.0, luma-theme

I'm wandering on the internet for my question and i didn't find an answer for such a silly question... Everywhere you can see Luma Theme with nice boxes and swatches and blocks etc. but when you choose Luma Theme you have none of them. How can I have these files installed on my magento? Where can I find all the Luma Blocks and Widget?

See attached

[image: a screenshot of the Luma Blocks]

Comment: you need to install simple data for magento to see blocks and content

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2 fresh setup,

Luma theme is already set.

You can change luma theme from `stores -> configraion -> design tab`.

Now if you are working with luma theme,

All pages from store are already defined with **Widgets.**

You can find all widgets from Admin panel.

```
Content -> Widgets
```

Go to widgets page and you have seen 18 widget defined for luma theme.

Also Block are defined for luma theme find from

```
Content -> Block
```

Plz let me know if any issue about this.

Comment: There are no widgets and no blocks in my magento... And also, if i try to create them myself css will not work! But Luma Theme is usable... i mean Luma is shown on frontend but no blocks are!